# Parsing Json using Vb.net Json.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, nullreferenceexception

Hey all I am getting the following error at random spots in my code:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I know why I am getting it. It does not find the correct property that I have it looking for and therefore it gives the error. Some may have that property and some, as this error shows, may not.

What can I do in order to check first to make sure it has that property? Currently I just have a Try/catch method in place so it can keep going if it does find something that's not there.

```
For Each Row In json("data")
  Try
    thePostID = DirectCast(Row("id").ToString(), String)
    thePostType = DirectCast(Row("type").ToString(), String)
    thePosterID = DirectCast(Row("from")("id").ToString(), String)
    thePosterName = DirectCast(Row("from")("name").ToString(), String)
  Catch ex As NullReferenceException
    msgbox("Did not find that particular property!")
  End Try
Next
```

**update**

```
{
"data": [
 {
   "id": "102zzz533zz_10z52zz9zzzz94z3", 
   "from": {
     "id": "102zzzzz95zzz7", 
     "name": "Jim zzzzz"
 }, 
 "likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "85zzzzz35zzzz0", 
        "name": "Anna zzzzz"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "10zzzz93z31zzzzz", 
        "name": "Vanessa zzzz zzzz"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "1zzz44zzz48731z6", 
        "name": "Leta zzzzzz"
      }
    ], 
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "after": "MTAyMdfasdfwrtMTkyNg=", 
        "before": "ODUasdfasrU5Mwerw"
      }
    }
  }
etc...
```

This JSON above follows in the same *data* path as all the others.

Using @Andrews code below:

```
thePostLikes = NullSafeSelect(Row, "likes.data.id")

If thePostLikes <> "NA" Then
   For Each Row2 In json("likes")("data")
      thePostLikesID += NullSafeSelect(Row2, "id") & ","
      thePostLikesName += NullSafeSelect(Row2, "name") & ","
   Next
End If
```

The value of **thePostLikes** is always *Nothing*

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more graceful way to do this that's built in to JSON.NET, but here's a helper function that will just return `Nothing` if the `path` you supply doesn't exist:

```
Function NullSafeSelect(ByVal obj As JToken, ByVal path As String) As String
    Dim result As String = Nothing
    Dim value As JToken = obj.SelectToken(path, False)

    if (value IsNot Nothing)
        result = value.ToString()
    End If

    Return value
End Function
```

You would call it from your loop like this:

```
For Each row in json("data")
    Dim thePostID As String = NullSafeSelect(row, "id")
    Dim thePostType As String = NullSafeSelect(row, "type")
    Dim thePosterId As String = NullSafeSelect(row, "from.id")
    ' ... etc

Next
```

Note that you do not need the `DirectCast` because the return type of the function is already `String`.

Comment: Alright but what about **DirectCast(Row("likes")("data")("id").ToString(), String)** and **DirectCast(Row("from")("id").ToString(), String)**? It seems to get one only from your function.

Comment: @StealthRT: Can you show your JSON? If `likes` is an array, you'll need to retrieve that value as an array and iterate through it as well

Comment: it would be just like your doing now.. just for the path instead of just **("soemthing")** it would need to be **(something)(something)(something)**.

Comment: @StealthRT: You should be able to use `likes.data.id`, assuming that `likes` is an object-- you can use a fairly complex path

Comment: look at my OP update. I have the other json code posted since i can not seem to get that working.

Comment: Any more help would be great!

Comment: @StealthRT: Working with the code you posted I can't duplicate any problems--`thePostLikesID` and `thePostLikesName` are both populated